# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (2) must match the size of tensor b (8) at non-singleton dimension 1

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model

I'm trying to build a transformer with positional encoder to create a regression model using PyTorch using the following code:

```
import math
import torch.nn as nn

class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, max_seq_len):
        super(Transformer, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.pos_encoding = PositionalEncoding(hidden_dim, max_seq_len)
        self.encoder_layers = nn.ModuleList([EncoderLayer(hidden_dim) for _ in range(num_layers)])
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.embedding(x)
        x = self.pos_encoding(x)
        for encoder_layer in self.encoder_layers:
            x = encoder_layer(x)
        x = self.output_layer(x.mean(dim=1))
        return x

class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_dim, max_seq_len):
        super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.1)
        pe = torch.zeros(max_seq_len, hidden_dim)
        position = torch.arange(0, max_seq_len, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, hidden_dim, 2).float() * (-math.log(10000.0) / hidden_dim))
        pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
        self.register_buffer('pe', pe.unsqueeze(0))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x + self.pe[:, :x.size(1)]
        x = self.dropout(x)
        return x

class EncoderLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_dim, dropout=0.1):
        super(EncoderLayer, self).__init__()
        self.feedforward = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim),
            nn.Dropout(p=dropout)
        )
        self.norm1 = nn.LayerNorm(hidden_dim)
        self.norm2 = nn.LayerNorm(hidden_dim)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.feedforward(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.norm1(x + x)
        x = self.norm2(x + x)
        return x
```

And To build it:

```
# Define the hyperparameters
input_dim = X1.shape[1]
hidden_dim = 16
num_layers = 2
num_heads = 8
lr = 1e-3
batch_size = 2
epochs = 1

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X1, y1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Convert the target variable to NumPy arrays
y_train = y_train.values
y_val = y_val.values

# Create the model and the optimizer
model = Transformer(input_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, num_heads)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

# Convert the data to PyTorch tensors
X_train = torch.tensor(X_train.values, dtype=torch.float)
X_val = torch.tensor(X_val.values, dtype=torch.float)
y_train = torch.tensor(y_train, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1)
y_val = torch.tensor(y_val, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1)

# Create the data loaders
train_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X_train, y_train)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X_val, y_val)
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

# Train the model
for epoch in range(epochs):
    # Train the model on the training set
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0
    for X_batch, y_batch in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        y_pred = model(X_batch)
        loss = criterion(y_pred,y_batch.view(1, -1))
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss.item() * X_batch.shape[0]
    train_loss /= len(train_dataset)
    print(epochs)

    # Evaluate the model on the validation set
    model.eval()
    val_loss = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for X_batch, y_batch in val_loader:
            y_pred = model(X_batch)
            loss = criterion(y_pred,y_batch.view(1, -1))

            val_loss += loss.item() * X_batch.shape[0]
        val_loss /= len(val_dataset)

    # Print the epoch number and the training and validation loss
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs}, Train Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, Val Loss: {val_loss:.4f}")
```

Then I'm getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-7b031268d55a> in <module>
      6     for X_batch, y_batch in train_loader:
      7         optimizer.zero_grad()
----> 8         y_pred = model(X_batch)
      9         loss = criterion(y_pred, y_batch).unsqueeze(1)
     10         loss.backward()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-27-b31310f27650> in forward(self, x)
     12     def forward(self, x):
     13         x = self.embedding(x)
---> 14         x = self.pos_encoding(x)
     15         for encoder_layer in self.encoder_layers:
     16             x = encoder_layer(x)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-27-b31310f27650> in forward(self, x)
     30 
     31     def forward(self, x):
---> 32         x = x + self.pe[:, :x.size(1)]
     33         x = self.dropout(x)
     34         return x

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (2) must match the size of tensor b (8) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

I tried to change the shape of the datframe, but it didn't work. And I'm not sure If I can change to TF instead of PyTorch as well

Comment: Please include the full error message

Comment: @Caridorc I modified it.

Comment: Please print the shapes of `x`, `self.pe` and `self.pe[:, :x.size(1)]` before the line `x = x + self.pe[:, :x.size(1)]`. The cause of the error will most probably also become clear to you when you will see the output

Comment: @Caridorc
torch.Size([2, 16])
torch.Size([1, 8, 16])
torch.Size([1, 8, 16])

So 2D and 3D and how to change the size? I'm not that familiar with PyTorch tbh

Comment: `x = x + self.pe[:, :x.size(0)]` because you were slicing with the dimension 1 of x that was 16 rather than 2. you may also need to squeeze / unsqueeze to handle the 2d / 3d disaparity